# End credit music sped up because of Chariot?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

Before entering The Chest (game over) I used a *The Chariot* card. After the end scene during the credits, the music was sped up similar to how The Chariot card speeds up the music in-game.
Is this because of The Chariot card or is it just how the music is in the credits after you beat The Chest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably due to *The Chariot* card. You can have a similar effect if you pick up *Stop Watch* or *Broken Watch*.

According to the [wikia](http://bindingofisaacrebirth.gamepedia.com/Broken_Watch):

> If the acceleration/slow down effect occurs in the final room of a run, the credits music and the title screen music will be sped up/slowed down